# Is there any way for me to fully qualify a discriminated union path?

Tags: f#, discriminated-union

**Is there any way for me to fully qualify a discriminated union path?**

I currently have this:

```
type PostionOfScott =
    | ScottOnFirst
    | ScottOnSecond
    | ScottOnThird

type PostionOfBrian =
    | BrianOnFirst
    | BrianOnSecond
    | BrianOnThird

type PostionOfCherice =
    | ChericeOnFirst
    | ChericeOnSecond
    | ChericeOnThird
```

I would like to do this:

```
type PostionOfScott =
    | First
    | Second
    | Third

type PostionOfBrian =
    | First
    | Second
    | Third

type PostionOfCherice =
    | First
    | Second
    | Third
```

However, when I provide the following code:

```
(*Functions*)
let hit play batterUp =

    match batterUp with
    | ScottAtBat   -> match play with
                      | Single  -> Scott First
                      | Double  -> Scott Second
                      | Tripple -> Scott Third
```

I receive the following error:

> Error     This expression was expected to have type
>       PostionOfScott     but here has type
>       PostionOfCherice

I understand that the last declared discriminated union type will be referenced if there's any ambiguity.

However, is there any way for me to fully qualify a discriminated union path?
Hence, I want to reduce verbiage within my union cases.

Comment: Change `| Single  -> Scott First` to `| Single  -> Scott PostionOfScott.First`, etc.

Comment: I think you have the wrong application logic.

Comment: Why not put out a `Postion` as a separate type?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think that repeating the position type definition for each player is probably not the best design choice.  It would make more sense to keep these things separate and then your problem goes away naturally.

```
type Position =
    | First
    | Second
    | Third

type Player =
    | Scott
    | Brian
    | Cherice

type PlayerPosition = {Player : Player; Position : Position}
```

Then you can pattern match:

```
let hit play batterUp =
    match batterUp with
    |{Player = Scott; Position = First} -> ...
```

Answer (score 5):

Sounds like you're looking for [RequireQualifiedAccess](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee340423.aspx) attribute.

```
[<RequireQualifiedAccess>]
type PositionOfScott =
    | First
    | Second
    | Third
```

With that, you'll need to use `PositionOfScott.First` instead of `First` outside of `PositionOfScott` members. Very useful for unions with generally nondescript values like `Yes` or `Any`.